# Python Loop and Append to String

Tags: python, string, loops

I have a string field and an array of numbers. When I iterate through the list I should get the string to append with the number from the array.

At the moment, it only returns the string + current position of the array. The following is my code. How could I solve this?

```
digit_list = list(map(int, str(extra_digits)))
pi_local = "PI"
for digit in range(len(digit_list)):
    pi_local = pi_local + str(digit_list[counter])
    pi_label.config(text = pi_local)
```

[initial incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yax97.png)

I have tried the suggestion below by trying to iterate over the list, but I am still not getting the right result. full code is below

```
pi = "PI"
extra_digits = "159265358979323846"


counter = 0
init = 2

#digit_list = list(map(int, str(extra_digits)))



def button_pressed():
    global counter
    global pi
    #global digit_list
    global init
    digit_list = list(map(int, str(extra_digits)))
    our_label.config(text="Pi to " + str(init+counter) + " decimals")
    pi_local = pi
    for digit in digit_list:
        pi_local = pi_local + str(digit)
        pi_label.config(text = str(digit))
        #pi_label.config(text = str(pi) + str(digit_list[counter]))
    counter = counter +  1
```

The output I am getting is [Current incorrect output after using solution below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqf4g.png)

Comment: could you clarify with given input output example what you expected

Comment: What is ˋcounterˋ? Are you aware that you can directly iterate over a list, without indexing? Why do you convert your input to a list of integers, when you only need a string?

Comment: What is your *expected* output? Also, please add your observed output as text instead of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [77]: pi_local = "PI"                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [78]: digit_list = [1,3,5,2]                                                                                                                                                                             

In [79]: [str(i) + pi_local for i in digit_list]                                                                                                                                                            
Out[79]: ['1PI', '3PI', '5PI', '2PI']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the elements in `digit_list`

```
digit_list = list(map(int, str(extra_digits)))
pi_local = "PI"
for digit in digit_list:
    pi_local = pi_local + str(digit)
    pi_label.config(text = pi_local)
```

Comment: Hi, My source data is as follows `extra_digits = "159265358979323846" ` and I converted that to a list map as well using `digit_list = list(map(int, str(extra_digits)))`

Comment: My requirement is that each time I click on the Next Digit button it appends the digit at the particular counter to my string being printed.